# Compiling Gstreamer SDK for Android on Windows 7

Tags: android-ndk, gstreamer

Trying to do Tutorial5 of *GStreamer SDK for Android*.

When I go into the Project Directory on a Cygwin 1.7 terminal and execute
`ndk-build`

I get

```
make: -n: Command not found
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c
/bin/sh: i: command not found
/cygdrive/c/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2012.10/share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer.mk:151: recipe for target `genstatic' failed
make: [genstatic] Error 127 (ignored)
/bin/sh: i: command not found
/cygdrive/c/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2012.10/share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer.mk:151: recipe for target `genstatic' failed
make: [genstatic] Error 127 (ignored)
/bin/sh: i: command not found
/cygdrive/c/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2012.10/share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer.mk:151: recipe for target `genstatic' failed
make: [genstatic] Error 127 (ignored)
/bin/sh: i: command not found
/cygdrive/c/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2012.10/share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer.mk:151: recipe for target `genstatic' failed
make: [genstatic] Error 127 (ignored)
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c
gst-build/gstreamer_android.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2012.10/share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer.mk:161: recipe for target `gst-build/gstreamer_android.o' failed
make: *** [gst-build/gstreamer_android.o] Error 1
```

Anybody know what is wrong?
I checked and I have *make (version 3.82.90)*

`gstreamer.mk:151` is the 2nd line of

```
# Generates a source file that declares and registers all the required plugins
genstatic:
    @$(HOST_ECHO) "GStreamer      : [GEN] => $(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_C)"
    @$(call host-mkdir,$(GSTREAMER_BUILD_DIR))
    @$(call host-cp,$(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_C_IN),$(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_C))
    @$(HOST_SED) -i "s/@PLUGINS_DECLARATION@/$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_DECLARE)/g" $(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_C)
    @$(HOST_SED) -i "s/@PLUGINS_REGISTRATION@/$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_REGISTER)/g" $(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_C)
    @$(HOST_SED) -i "s/@G_IO_MODULES_LOAD@/$(G_IO_MODULES_LOAD)/g" $(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_C)
    @$(HOST_SED) -i "s/@G_IO_MODULES_DECLARE@/$(G_IO_MODULES_DECLARE)/g" $(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_C)
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks LCID Fire, I edited but couldn't get it to stay in the code box.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your cygwin installation. Did you try to execute `make`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure *shell* in `tools.mk` points to your environment shell.

I.e. /usr/bin/bash or /bin/bash in cygwin.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the latest releases **ndk-build** do not survive **cygwin** shell. The workaround is either to use an old version of **ndk**, or to open a **cmd** prompt to run **ndk-build**.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ifeq ($(HOST_OS),cygwin)
  HOST_SED := $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/tools/windows/sed
  GSTREAMER_LD :=
else
endif
```

To your gstreamer.mk